# How can I open multiple Chrome tabs from python?

Tags: python, google-chrome

I want to open multiple Chrome tabs from within a program

The following command works perfectly from the terminal

```
google-chrome-stable www.google.com www.yahoo.com
```

How ever, when I run a python program containing

```
tabs = 'www.google.com www.yahoo.com'
subprocess.run(['google-chrome-stable', tabs],
                       stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                       shell=False)
```

then urls get converted to

```
http://www.google.com%20www.yahoo.com/
```

How can I fix this?

I have tried

```
tabs = ['www.google.com', 'www.yahoo.com']
for tab in tabs:
    subprocess.run(['google-chrome-stable', tab],
                           stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                           shell=False)
```

But the program halts after each tab is opened and will not start again until the Chrome window containing the url is closed.

[Edit]
Chrome is not my default browser and I don't want it to be, but I must use it for this application as there is a bespoke plug-in that I need to use

Comment: Are you trying to open chrome multiple times or webpages multiple times

Comment: @UjjwalDash Preferably one Chrome window with multiple tabs.

Answer (score 1):

Try this it may work

```py
import webbrowser
websites = ['www.google.com', 'www.reddit.com']
for url in websites:
    webbrowser.open(url)
```